# Windows Word says, "There is insufficient memory or disk space. Close extra windows and save your work"

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-word, memory-management

While pasting an image in a Microsoft Word Document, I got this error message:

[image: There is insufficient memory or disk space. Close extra windows and save your work.]

I was only having Microsoft Word, Windows Paint, Google Chrome and Windows Explorer open at that point of time - nothing more than usual.

Also, I make it a point to never have much background processes and/or sidebar items. At the particular point of time, I was just having Download Accelerator Plus (in case I click on any link to download anything in Google Chrome) and my Samsung Galaxy Y mobile phone connected with USB Storage on.

Anyhow, after closing everything other than Word, I was able to paste the image.

What's the problem? Should I be worrying? What steps and measures can I adopt to make sure this doesn't happens again?

Comment: It sounds like the image you are trying to copy and paste is to large to fit in the clipboard.  Verify the size of the allowed clipboard.

Comment: You seem to be using a beta version of Microsoft Windows 8. Perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes, I use Beta version of Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that it's offering you two options--memory or disk space.  You're going through explaining what you have in memory and saying nothing about how full your disk is.

Note that closing programs could have freed up space from the swap file and thus gotten you more disk space.

Go to My Computer and check how much free space you have on drive C.  I strongly suspect it's no more than a few gb which effectively means zero if you don't have a preallocated swap file.

Comment: I have 100 GB total space in C, out of which 71 GB is free.